# Cannot Instantiate driver file, getting:- insmod: ERROR: could not insert module crc8/crc8.ko: Invalid module format

Tags: sensor, kernel, driver, modules

To integrate a flow sensor with RPi, I am following the [Tutorial: Using Differential Pressure and Flow Sensors with Raspberry Pi](https://developer.sensirion.com/archive/tutorials/raspberry-pi-tutorial-using-flow-sensors/). However, as the git repo being used ro install the linux kernel headers is for Python 2.7 and has been archived, I am using it's newer version maintained by the same author at [this repo](https://github.com/RPi-Distro/rpi-source).

```
$ sudo wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RPi-Distro/rpi-source/master/rpi-source -O /usr/local/bin/rpi-source && sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/rpi-source && /usr/local/bin/rpi-source -q --tag-update
$ $ sudo apt install gcc-aarch64-linux-gnu
$ export CROSS_COMPILE=aarch64-linux-gnu-
$ rpi-source
```

This installs the rpi-source tool from Github, installs a dependency of the kernel build process, and downloads the source code for the kernel version running on my Pi, which is 6.1.21-v8+.
After this, I am cloning the driver and compiling it.
mkdir drivers

```
$ cd drivers/
$ git clone https://github.com/Sensirion/sfxx.git
$ git clone https://github.com/Sensirion/crc8.git
 
$ echo obj-y := crc8/ sfxx/ > Makefile
$ make -C ~/linux M=$PWD
```

Everything works till this point. However, when I am trying to load the modules and instantiate the driver, I am getting the error:

```
$ sudo insmod crc8/crc8.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module crc8/crc8.ko: Invalid module format
```

I am not able to fix this and get my sensor up and running. Any advise on this would really help a lot.